# Momentum and Kinetic energy from a decay of single particle at rest into 2 particles

Tags: special-relativity, kinematics, nuclear-physics, conservation-laws, mass-energy

How can I find the kinectic energy $KE_n = E_n - m_nc^2$ and the momentum $ p_n = \frac{1}{c}\sqrt{E_n^2 - m_n^2c^4}$

From $E_n = (\frac{m_{\lambda}^2 + m_n^2 - m_p^2}{2m{_\lambda}})c^2$, which result from a decay of a single particle at rest into 2 particles. My book just give me the equations without the path.

Since I have 2 downvotes I'll try to explain myself. Since, I have nothing more in my book, I don't know if this is more complex than algebra.

Using the conservation laws and $E^2 = p^2c^2 + m^2c^4$ I can't find the momentum, since I don't know where the 2 other masses goes.

Comment: The down votes may be due to lack of details and clarity.  What is the situation you are trying to model?  What are the suffixes $n, p, \lambda$?

Comment: They are just particles. I mean in my book I don't have much details in this sub section. The autor only say that we can get those equations from a decay of a single particle at rest into 2 particles, one massless and one massive or both massive. Thus, I assume that p is probably for photon in this case. That's pretty much all that I have and this lack of details makes me confuse.

Comment: I should be able to get the expression above for the kinetic energy and momentum using $E_n = (\frac{m_{\lambda}^2 + m_n^2 - m_p^2}{2m{_\lambda}})c^2$. For instance, for a massive particle and a massless particle I can get rid of $m_p^2$ since the photon is massless. However it doesn't help since I should get both the expression even if both particles is massive.

Comment: You should show us how you used conservation of momentum as that will lead you to the answer, but without any way to see how you did it we are left to guess what you did wrong. As a hint, if the parent particle was at rest, think on what the only possible directions the two resulting particles can move.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notation is slightly strange, but I don't see the need to downvote. To describe the process that you've outlined (and make a connection to the formula you have written), consider a particle at rest with four-momenta $P=\left(\frac{E}{c},0\right)$ and mass $M$. The energy of the particle is given by $$P^2=-\left(\frac{E}{c}\right)^2=-M^2c^2\implies E=Mc^2.$$ Now suppose that the particle decays into two daughter particles each with four momentum $P_1=\left(\frac{E_1}{c},\vec{p}_1\right)$ and $P_2=\left(\frac{E_2}{c},\vec{p}_2\right)$, and of mass $m_1$ and $m_2$ respectively. To describe the decay process, we can use conservation of energy and momentum which is given by $$P=P_1+P_2\iff P_1=P-P_2.$$
We can square both sides to get $$P_1^2=(P-P_2)^2=P^2-2P\cdot P_2+P_2^2=-M^2c^2-m_2^2c^2+2ME_2$$ $$\implies E_2=\left(\frac{M^2+m_2^2-m_1^2}{2M}\right)c^2.$$
Here I am using the mostly plus Minkowski metric $\eta_{\mu\nu}=\text{diag}(-,+,+,+)$ and used the fact that $P_1^2=-m_1^2c^2$ and $P_2^2=-m_2^2c^2$. We can also get a similar formula for $E_1$, given by $$E_1=\left(\frac{M^2+m_1^2-m_2^2}{2M}\right)c^2.$$Just as a sanity check, if we add $E_1$ and $E_2$, we do indeed get $E$ back, which we require from energy conservation. To work out the momentum of each daughter particle, we first note that from conservation of momentum we have $$0=\vec{p}_1+\vec{p}_2\iff\vec{p}_1=-\vec{p}_2.$$ To get the momentum, say $\vec{p}_1$, we simply use the energy-momentum relation $$E_1^2=m_1^2c^4+\vec{p}_1\cdot\vec{p}_1c^2\implies ||\vec{p}_1||=\frac{1}{c}\sqrt{E_1^2-m_2^2c^4}.$$ Similarly, we can get a similar formula for $\vec{p}_2$. The magnitude the momentum of both daughter particles will be the same, but the particles will travel in opposite directions. If you want a more explicit formula, plug the energy into the equation and do the algebra. As for the kinetic energy, you simply plug in the energy for each daughter particle into the equation $$KE=E-mc^2.$$ For for daughter particle 1 lets say, we would have $$KE_1=E_1-m_1c^2=\left(\frac{M^2+m_1^2-m_2^2-2Mm_1}{2M}\right)c^2=\left(\frac{(M-m_1)^2-m_2^2}{2M}\right)c^2.$$Similarly, we can get a formula for $KE_2$. These equations are valid for both massive and massless particles. For example, suppose daughter particle 1 was massless. We would then have $m_1=0$. Then $$E_1=\left(\frac{M^2-m_2^2}{2M}\right)c^2\quad\text{and}\quad E_2=\left(\frac{M^2+m^2_2}{2M}\right)c^2.$$Then the massless particle would have momentum $$||\vec{p}_1||:=p_1=\frac{M^2-m_2^2}{2M}$$ and so on. I hope this clears up any confusion.